# Finding $2 \pi \sum_{i=0}^N \left(1 - \frac{a}{a + b - i c}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: summation

Is it possible to solve the following series?

$$2 \pi  \sum_{i=0}^N \left(1 - \frac{a}{a + b - i c}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

where $a,b,c$ are parameters.

Since $a \gg b,c,N$, solving the Taylor expansion might also do the trick:

$$3 \pi \sum_{i=0}^N \left(1 - \frac{a}{a + b - i c}\right)$$

But I'm not able to solve this either.

I don't think it helps but the upper limit is:

$N = \frac{b}{c}$

Comment: I don’t see any reason to think there is a closed form. You might be able to get upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Wolfram gives this [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28j%3D1%29%5EN+%28+1+-+a%2F%28a%2Bk-%28j-1%29*b%29%29&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Sum%22%2C+%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Sum%22%2C+%22sumfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%28+1+-+a%2F%28a%2Bk-x*b%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Sum%22%2C+%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D+-%3E%22k%2Fb%22)  but it's rather complicate

Comment: And I can't see the step-by-step solution

Comment: Here a correct Wolfram Alpha answer. Even more complicated. And this is without the $3/2$ exponent. 
[Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28+1+-+a%2F%28a%2Bk-%28j%29*b%29%29+%2Cj%3D0to+N)

Comment: The digamma function Wofram Alpha uses in the answer is a frequent way to hide a finite sum. For example, for integers $n$:$$\psi^{(0)}(n)=\psi(n)=\left(\sum_1^{n-1}\frac1k\right)-\lambda$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Comment: Yeah I guess there is no solution apart from that one, thanks anyway

Comment: In particular, the WA answer has the term: $\psi(x+y)-\psi(x)$ and: $$\psi(x+y)-\psi(x)=\frac1{x+1}+\cdots+\frac1{ x+y-1}$$